# formControlName com *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Eu tenho um form com 3 campos q serão usados pelo usuario: um select, um textarea e um input.

Esses campos sao preenchidos com um ngFor q os dados vem do banco:

```
<form id="form-group" [formGroup]="AddForm">
  <div>

    <div class="row p-3 hours_week" *ngFor="let subType of day1">
      <!-- ! -->
      <div class="col text-light">
        <p>Data:</p>
        <p class="text-light" formControlName="DATA_DIA">{{formatDate(subType.DATA_DIA)}}</p>
      </div>
      <!-- ! -->
      <div class="col text-light">
        <label>Cod.Evento:</label><br>
        <label>{{subType.CODIGO_EVENTO}}</label>
      </div>
      <!-- ! -->
      <div class="col text-light">
        <label>Descrição:</label><br>
        <label>{{subType.DESCRICAO}}</label>
      </div>
      <!-- ! -->
      <div class="col text-light">
        <label>Tipo da Marc:</label><br>
        <label>{{subType.TIPO_MARC}}</label>
      </div>
      <!-- ! -->
      <div class="col text-light">
        <label>Qtde.Calcul:</label><br>
        <label>{{replace_all(subType.QT_CAL_SIS,".",":")}}</label>
      </div>
      <!-- ! -->
      <div class="col text-light">
        <label>Motivo:</label><br>
        <select [name]="subType.RESULT+motivoHtml" formControlName="MOTIVO">
          <option value="" selected>Motivos</option>
          <option *ngFor="let motivos of motivo" value="{{motivos.CODIGO_MOTIVO}}">{{motivos.DESCRICAO}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <!-- ! -->
      <div class="col text-light">
        <label>Obs:</label><br>
        <textarea formControlName="OBS" cols="50" rows="2" placeholder="Observação" type="text" class="form-control"
           min="0" max="10"> </textarea>
      </div>
      <!-- ! -->
      <div class="col text-light">
        <label>Arquivo:</label><br>
        <input formControlName="UPLOAD" type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" multiple id="{{subType}}SlotsInput"
           class="text-light" (change)="inputFileChange($event)" multiple>
      </div>
      <!-- ! -->
      <span class="linha" *ngIf="onClass"></span>
      <!-- ! -->



    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- ! -->

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button_salve btn-lg" (click)="finalizar()">Finalizar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg button_cancel" [routerLink]="['/bh-home']">Cancelar</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- ! -->

</form>
```

só que o AddForm só pega o ultimo dado preenchido do ngFor, sendo q preciso pegar todos.
Tem como eu utilizar o formControlName pegando todos os dados do *ngFor?

Answer (score 0):

O **FormGroup** serve para agrupar respostas de **inputs** e o **formControlName** serve para pegar dados digitado é armazenar em uma variável e passar essa informação para o **FormGroup** para que você possa estar trabalhando com elas, nesse caso precisaria explicar melhor o que você está pretendo fazer e colocar o aquivo **component.ts** para que possa analisar.

Respondendo sua pergunta sim e possível, o **formControlName** só pegou o último dado pois e um **input** recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação do [angular](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName). você pode usar o [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) para te ajudar nesse formulário, você vai encontrar muitos exemplos lá.

Espero ter ajudado.